# Postman automatically resets environment variable Current Value to null

Tags: postman

I have an environment with few variables set in Initial Values.

```
//Variable, Initial Value, Current Value

 VAR 1, Initial 1, null

 VAR 2, Initial 2, null
```

I updated the environment Current Values to Initial Values by clicking Reset All. My environment now looks like this and I save it.

```
//Variable, Initial Value, Current Value

 VAR 1, Initial 1, Initial 1

 VAR 2, Initial 2, Initial 2
```

Now, when I run my collection requests, I get the following error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND null
```

Upon checking my environment variables, I see the current value resets to null again. Any idea why this is happening ? Am I missing something obvious. There are also nothing set in the Tests.

```
 //Variable, Initial Value, Current Value

 VAR 1, Initial 1, null

 VAR 2, Initial 2, null
```

Comment: how do you expect someone to debugg this ? please add the code where you retrieves the variable and sets the variable :D

Comment: see if you are setting environment variable from script accidently

Comment: Also make sure after clicking reset , save the environment

Comment: @PDHide There are no scripts as I mentioned. I saved it after manually setting the current values to initial values. The current values are automatically reset to null upon running the request.

Comment: create a new collection and a new fresh request and send it and see the behaviour is seen again. if not then check if there is any collection level script or you misspelt pm.environment.get as pm.enviroment.set

Comment: @PDHide OMG THANK YOU ! I didn't realize there's a collection level script. It's driving me insane. I removed it and it is working as intended now.

Comment: Cool :) i avoid collection level due to this reason . ITs easier to make mistake and will completely forget we had something there

Comment: @PDHide Thanks - I inherited these postman collections, never realize there's a collection level scripts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To debug such issues try out the following steps:**

1. Create a new collection and a new fresh request and send it and see the behaviour is seen again
2. Check if there is any collection level script
3. Check if you misspelt pm.environment.get as pm.environment.set
4. Make sure after clicking reset, or editing variables you save the environment